# Create new for loop from for loop in Django

Tags: python, django

If you look at the piece of code below, you will understand exactly what I want. Enough even if I only get the number of cars that comply with this condition. Or it would be great if we could create a new loop from cars that comply with this condition.

```
{% for car in cars %}
    {% if car.color == 'white' %}
            create new for loop from white cars
            or
            give me the numbers of white cars
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you share the view that is generating the cars context variable?

Comment: Edit and post your views.py

Comment: in view.py you should create data with white cars and send it to template. If you want more colors then in view.py you should group cars by color and send as list/dict these groups.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do it in a template. Modify your ORM query statement.

```
white_cars = Car.objects.filter(color='white')
```

And use it in your template with single loop.

```
{% for car in white_cars %}
    // Your code
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: this is very big data and very grouped so I can not filter from orm.

Comment: Why not? Filtering in database is better choice.

Comment: Because I need to filter according to the arguments in html and I don't know in advance what to filter in the rendered html.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regroup` template tag to group the list of cars by the color and then select the list of cars with white color to iterate over.

```
{% regroup cars by color as cars_grouped_by_color %}



{% for cars in cars_grouped_by_color %}
  {% if cars.grouper == 'white' %}
    {% for car in cars.list %}
      ...
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Refer [regroup documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) for more details.